# Unable to navigate to Magento - Nginx web server

Tags: nginx, magento2, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I've installed Magento along with Nginx and now I am able to see the localhost welcome Nginx page and I cant navigate to Magento site.

I would want an idea what can I add or remove so I can navigate to the localhost and open the Magento site.

When I run nginx -t the test is successful,I need only to navigate to Magento site using Nginx.

This is how the configurations look like:

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.conf**

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
 server unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}

server {

 listen 80;
 server_name test.mgt.com www.test.mgt.com;
#   root /var/www/magento2;
 set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2/html;
 set $MAGE_MODE developer;
 index index.html index.phtml index.php;
### Loading Magento 2 nginx config ###

 include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample; #Mage2
 add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/magento.conf**

```
server {

  #      listen 443 ssl;
    #    server_name magento.hakase-labs.pw;

    #    ssl on;
     #   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento.hakase-labs.pw/fullchain>
       # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento.hakase-labs.pw/privk>

 listen 80;
server_name test.mgt.com;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
        set $MAGE_MODE developer;
        include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/magento.conf**

```
server {

  #      listen 443 ssl;
    #    server_name magento.hakase-labs.pw;

    #    ssl on;
     #   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento.hakase-labs.pw/fullchain>
       # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento.hakase-labs.pw/privk>

 listen 80;
server_name test.mgt.com;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
        set $MAGE_MODE developer;
        include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

**
/var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample**

```
server {

  #      listen 443 ssl;
    #    server_name magento.hakase-labs.pw;

    #    ssl on;
     #   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento.hakase-labs.pw/fullchain>
       # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento.hakase-labs.pw/privk>

 listen 80;
server_name test.mgt.com;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
        set $MAGE_MODE developer;
        include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}



/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
/var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample


root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
 fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cry>
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
 }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_c>
        deny all;
    }
 alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser>
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf>
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf>
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
}
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check>
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua>
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't m>
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

I tried all configurations and all the settings and I was expecting Magento to open up with nginx but it wasnt able to